How to send data from parachain to relaycahin
Hello everyone I am working on a project where I need to send some data or messages from my custom parachain to a custom relaychain, then I want to map with a particular account and store it on relaychain. can anyone guide me on this?  I am using polkadot-sdk template for relaychain and substrate-parachain-template for parachain. thank you
